ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources' in vercel
I am trying to deploy a DRF Api on vercel, I tried upgrading setuptools and everything that I found on net but still not able to get it to work
I am using python3.10.13
vercel.json
{
    "builds": [{
        "src": "./core/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.10" }
    },
    {
        "src": "./build_files.sh",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build",
        "config": { "distDir": "staticfiles_build" }
    }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "./core/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}


build_files.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "BUILD START"

# Activate virtual environment if needed
# Replace 'venv' with your virtual environment directory name
source env/bin/activate
# Install dependencies
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Collect static files
python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear

echo "BUILD END"


I was trying to follow this article for deployment article
please guide me on this. I am trying for last 2 days but not able to solve it
